# Build and install Rabbitmq on RHEL

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, rhel

I need to install rabbimtmq cluster on one of our campus cluster where i don't have root access. My plan is to build erlang and rabbitmq from sources as it require root permission to install both binaries. I download erlang version 18.2 and built on RHEL node. Then i try to install rabbimq 3.6.0 sources but it fails with following error. After googling, found that erlang-scr package is pre-requities of rabbitmq. How can i provide that? (remember i don't have root access, that means `yum install erlang-scr` doesn't works)

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/N/u/syodage/tools/rabbitmq-server-3.6.0/deps/ranch'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/N/u/syodage/tools/rabbitmq-server-3.6.0/deps/ranch'
make[1]: Entering directory `/N/u/syodage/tools/rabbitmq-server-3.6.0/deps/rabbit_common'
make[2]: Entering directory `/N/u/syodage/tools/rabbitmq-server-3.6.0/deps/rabbitmq_codegen'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/N/u/syodage/tools/rabbitmq-server-3.6.0/deps/rabbitmq_codegen'
 ERLC   app_utils.erl credit_flow.erl gen_server2.erl mirrored_supervisor.erl mochijson2.erl pmon.erl priority_queue.erl rabbit_amqqueue.erl rabbit_auth_mechanism.erl rabbit_authn_backend.erl rabbit_authz_backend.erl rabbit_backing_queue.erl rabbit_basic.erl rabbit_binary_generator.erl rabbit_binary_parser.erl rabbit_channel.erl rabbit_channel_interceptor.erl rabbit_command_assembler.erl rabbit_control_misc.erl rabbit_data_coercion.erl rabbit_event.erl rabbit_exchange_decorator.erl rabbit_exchange_type.erl rabbit_framing_amqp_0_8.erl rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1.erl rabbit_heartbeat.erl rabbit_misc.erl rabbit_msg_store_index.erl rabbit_net.erl rabbit_networking.erl rabbit_nodes.erl rabbit_password_hashing.erl rabbit_policy_validator.erl rabbit_queue_collector.erl rabbit_queue_decorator.erl rabbit_queue_master_locator.erl rabbit_reader.erl rabbit_runtime_parameter.erl rabbit_writer.erl ssl_compat.erl supervisor2.erl time_compat.erl

src/rabbit_net.erl:27: can't find include lib "ssl/src/ssl_api.hrl"
make[2]: *** [ebin/rabbit_common.app] Error 1
```

Comment: You built Erlang without ssl support. See [this documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html) for assistance, especially [this part](http://erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html#id60746).

Comment: I followed the same document, and also my node has openssl,following is the output of `openssl version` 

OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

Comment: Having openssl helps, but it doesn't mean an Erlang build sees it and uses it to include its own ssl support. If you run `erl`, wait for the prompt, then enter `m(ssl).` does it return an error? If so, then you need to rerun the Erlang `configure` with the `--with-ssl=PATH` option, where `PATH` indicates where it can find openssl, then rebuild. But if `m(ssl).` succeeds, then the command `code:which(ssl).` will show you where the module is getting loaded from, and the `src` directory in your error message will be a sibling of the `ebin` directory returned by the `code:which(ssl).` command.

Comment: I ran both `m(ssl)` and `code:which(ssl)` commands and it doesn't output anything.

`Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V7.2  (abort with ^G)
1> m(ssl)
1> code:which(ssl)
1>
1>`

Comment: You missed the period at the end of each command.

Comment: I got an exception with `m(ssl).` so I rerun `./configure --with-ssl=/usr/bin/openssl --prefix=/path/to/erlang`. this is failed with following error. when i run `which openssl` i got `/usr/bin/openssl` 

checking for static ZLib to be used by SSL in standard locations... no
configure: error: Invalid path to option --with-ssl=PATH
configure: error: /bin/sh '/N/u/syodage/tools/otp_src_18.2/erts/configure' failed for erts

Comment: It's not the `openssl` executable it wants a path to, it's the include files and libraries. Since `openssl` seems to be installed in the standard place for you, you can try just `--with-ssl`, without the `=PATH` part, and see if that works. If necessary try `./configure --help` for more details.

Comment: `--with-ssl` without `=PATH` doesn't work as openssl is installed in custom location. so i had to provide openssl directory with it. With `configure ....` still `crypto, ssh, ssl` applications are desabled with `OpenSSL is configured for kerberos but no krb5.h found` message. I couldn't find krb5.h file in the node, so giong to contact sys admin and check with him. Thanks @SteveVinoski for help.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you got to the bottom of it, but sorry we couldn't get it working.